# Storing the dictionary's keys in the dictionary when defining dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, variables

I want to be able to store the keys of a dictionary in the dictionary, preferably defining the dictionary only once. I am unsure if this is possible as it very close to recursively defining variables but what I want is:

```py
d = {
            "a" : d.keys()
}
```

### My attempts

The only approaches I have come up with are the following:

#### Using Eval

```py
d = {
            "a" : 'd.keys()' #stored as a string for future execution
}
```

This works but isn't ideal.

#### Using separate passes

```py
d = {
            "a" : None
}
d = {
            "a" : d.keys()
}
```

This works but I would prefer one to only define my dictionary once. I also don't want to store another list of keys and take that approach.

Comment: Why do you want this, what is the use case? Should the keys be dynamically updated, or just static when the dictionary is initialized? Presumably the former base on your string eval, but what is the benefit over accessing `d.keys()` when you need it?

Comment: At the time you're attempting to call `d.keys()`, `d` doesn't exist yet and the dictionary isn't done being defined yet. Consider `return { 'a': NOW WHAT }`… You can only do that after the fact if at all. But, by definition, a dictionary stores its keys as `d.keys()`, so it's unclear why you need a key inside the dictionary storing the keys…

Comment: I wish to write a dictionary of commands, the validation requirements are to be stored in the dictionary as a set of valid parameters. One of the sets should be the key of the dictionary, meaning only commands in the dictionary can be in the set of valid parameters. They will be static.

Comment: Maybe you can describe the problem in which you need such an implementation, because it seems a bit convoluted what you need, there might be other options

Comment: There is basically one special case command, 'help' which you can give a parameter `!help <command>` but that command must be in the dictionary of commands. Help is defined in the dictionary with the rest at the moment, would it be best to uncouple help from this dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do this:

```
d = dict()
d.update({"a": d.keys()})
d.update({"c": "dfghjk"})
d.update({"f": "dfjk"})
print(d.get("a"))
```

prints:
    dict_keys(['a', 'c', 'f'])

Comment: This worked! But required that `d.keys()` was referential as doing `set(d.keys())` would return `[]` and never be updated